# How to handle Realm React Native migrations and schemaVersion on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

Before I fall in love with realm on react-native and iOS, I am trying to learn more about how I can handle migrations.  This statement has me concerned:

**Realm React Native 0.10.0**

- https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#migrations

> Migrations are currently limited to updating the schema and
>   schemaVersion when opening a Realm as outlined above. Data migrations
>   are not yet supported but may be added in the future.

I understand this to mean I need to increment schemaVersion **each time I make a change to **any** schema**.

**How can I specify multiple schemas, each with their own schema versions ?**

This does NOT work:

```
export default new Realm(
  {schema: [AppSetting], schemaVersion: 0},
  {schema: [Gps], schemaVersion: 3},
  {schema: [Waypoint], schemaVersion: 4},
  {schema: [FlightPath], schemaVersion: 1},
);
```

This assumes that my more complicated schemas might need to be revised frequently until I get things right.

Will migrations be simple as long as I only add new properties?

I assume I cannot rename or remove existing properties?

Advice on realm migrations is much appreciated,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify a single schemaVersion for your entire schema:

```
export default new Realm({schema: [AppSetting, Gps, ...], schemaVersion: 0});
```

When you update any of the objectSchema in your schema you need to bump your schemaVersion. What this means is that some individual objectSchema will remain the same across multiple schemaVersions but I think this is less complicated than having different versions for each object type.

When you initialize a Realm with a new schemaVersion/schema, all new properties are added and missing properties and removed. So if you rename a property this will end up adding a new property with the new name, and removing the old property along with its data. For now if you want to copy data from one property to another you need to do it in two steps, so both the old property and new property exist at the same time allowing you to do the copy. You would also need to keep track of whether you did the copy so you only perform this the first time the the Realm is opened with the new schema. If you are only adding properties you can avoid most if not all of this complexity.

We didn't have time to finish migrations for the initial release, but the good news is most of the functionality is implemented internally and just needs to be exposed through the js apis. How things will work is you will be able to pass a migration function when opening a Realm which will give you access to both the pre and post migrated Realms allowing you to copy data as needed. We hope to have this completed in one of the next few releases.

Comment: @Ari How can old and new exist at same time so that I can copy data to new format?  Assuming I renamed a property and I need to copy old to new, how do I do this?  When I run the first time with new schemaVersion, will the old property name be removed *before* I get a chance to copy to property with the new name?

Comment: @Ed. At the moment you need to have a schemaVersion where both properties exist at the same time - so instead of renaming, you need to update to a format with both properties at which time you can do the copy, and then in the next schema change you can remove the old property. This is obviously inconvenient and we are working on proper support for data migrations including at some point automatic support for property renaming.

Comment: 1) Make a new schema, 2) Make a "run-once" schema that combines old schema and new schema, 3) Deploy both "run-once" and new schema with new release, 4) Manually migrate using "run-once" schema, 5) Close "run-once" schema, then load new schema.  Is this what the work-around would look like?

Comment: @Ari I expected **no migration to be required when adding new properties**. Is this not correct?  All object schemaVersion fields were set to 0 and incremented to 1 for the new schemaVersion.  I get a red box error saying "**Migration is required**" because of the new properties I added to object models? Am I missing something?

Comment: `export default new Realm({schema: [
  AppSetting,
  Waypoint,
  Boreplan,
]});`

Comment: Never mind, not specifying schemaVersion defaults to 0. When only adding new properties, specifying the schema version worked with no migration required. `export default new Realm({
  schema: [
    AppSetting,
    Waypoint,
    Boreplan,
  ],
  schemaVersion: 1
});`

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the latest version of Realm supports data migrations, so you can rename properties with a single schema change and can copy over property values in the migration function. https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#migrations